# Can a sciposter be in portrait, but with 2 columns?

Tags: two-column, multicolumn, posters, sciposter

I am prepairing a poster and I really liked this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modelo-poster-gcom-pet/hzfjzmkgtmch) with `\documentclass{sciposter}`. Is there a way to keep everything the same but change the number of columns from 3 to 2? Tnx

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the TeX file for the poster you can find the line

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
```

Change it to

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
```